# Why do I get a warning when using AndroidView as the key of DisposableEffect?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

Is this writing method standard? Why do I get a warning?

```kotlin
 DisposableEffect(
        AndroidView(factory = {
            TextureView(context).apply {
            }
        })
    ) {
        onDispose {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a Composable as the `key` parameter of a `DisposableEffect`, which does not quite make sense.

`DisposableEffect` is there to trigger [side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) that should be cleaned up. The code within the `DisposableEffect` is executed once whenver the value provided as `key` parameter changes.

In your case, you are passing a Composable directly as `key` parameter. Composables basically are of type `() -> Unit`, so the compiler probably detects that your function returns a `Unit` and thus takes this as a key.

I am not sure if there is a use case in general to use a Composable within `DisposableEffect`, but if there is any, you probably want to do

```
DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            TextureView(context).apply {}
        }
    )

    onDispose {
    }
}
```

I think however that this is not a good design.